# Remote JMS @Resource injection into EJBs

Tags: jboss, ejb, jms, jndi, jboss5.x

Does anyone know if it is possible to inject a JMS Queue as a @Resource when the jms queue is provided by a remote server.

I'm using Jboss 5.1 with JBoss Messaging. We have a client program on a different JBoss server that needs to post messages to this remote queue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Resource` annotation has a `name` attribute in which you can specify the JNDI name of the component you want to inject. The container will however prefix it with `java:comp/env`, so that means that it will look up resources in your local JNDI namespace.

You will have to perform a programmatic JNDI lookup for this as far as I know.

Comment: This is what I thought. I didn't know whether there was a way to configure an mbean that would allow me to "see" the remote jms queue in the local jndi tree